# Help with Borel Cantelli lemma

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, normal-distribution, borel-cantelli-lemmas

> There is a sequence of random variables $X_1,X_2,...$ such that for each $i$, $X_i\sim N(0,1)$.
>
> Does $ \frac{X_n}{n} \rightarrow 0 $ almost surely?
>
> Does $ \frac{X_n}{\ln n} \rightarrow 0 $ almost surely?
>
> Use Borel Cantelli lemma on solution.

I would glad if you can give me a solution on that question because i have no idea what to do here... Borel Cantelli lemma is (very!) not intuitive to me...

Also it will be helpful if you can tell me what "almost surely convergence" means?

Comment: I consider that but i thought this law is work only on the summation x1+x2+.. also the hint of borel cantelli seem important... 
can you show how can i use the strong law in the first one?

Comment: Sorry, I actually misread the question -- my bad. Ignore my comment...

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to give it a shot -- Borel-Cantelli is a tad hazy in my mind, though, so you **definitely** should doublecheck.

Fix any $\epsilon > 0$, and define the event $$E_n\stackrel{\rm{}def}{=} \mathbb{1}_{\left\{\frac{\lvert X_n\rvert}{n}\geq \epsilon\right\}}$$
so that
$$ \mathbb{P} E_n  = \mathbb{P}\left\{ \lvert X_n\rvert \geq n\epsilon \right\} = \operatorname{erfc}\left(\frac{\epsilon n}{ \sqrt{2} }\right) \operatorname*{\sim}_{n\to\infty} \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \frac{e^{-\frac{\epsilon^2n^2}{2}}}{\epsilon n}$$
and thus $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb{P} E_n < \infty$. By Borel-Cantelli,
$$ \mathbb{P}\left(\limsup_{n\to\infty} E_n\right) = 0 $$
that is, 
$$ \forall \epsilon > 0, \forall_{\rm{}a.s.} \omega\in\Omega,\ \exists N\geq 0,\forall n\geq N,\ \frac{\lvert X_n\rvert}{n}< \epsilon$$
or, equivalently, $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\lvert X_n\rvert}{n}\to0$ a.s.

This also seems to work for $\frac{X_n}{\ln n}$, as $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{e^{-\frac{\epsilon^2}{2}\ln^2n}}{\epsilon \ln n} < \infty.$$

Comment: what did you calculated for $\mathbb P\{|X_n|\ge n\epsilon\}$ and why do we need $|X_n|$ there as one can directly apply Markov's Inequality to conclude $\mathbb P\{X_n\ge n\epsilon\}\le  \frac{\mathbb E(X_n)}{n\epsilon}=0$ each $X_i$ follows $N(0,1)$

Comment: @bunny Markov's inequality is for **nonnegative** random variables.

Comment: but in the proof we do not use any non negative conditions

Comment: @bunny I don't understand what you mean. In the proof of Markov's inequality?

Comment: i was reading from Amir Dembo notes and there in the statement itself he has no restriction on $X_n$ to be non negative

Comment: Well, there should. I don't know which notes you are referring to, but the statement without nonnegativity is just wrong.

Comment: in this link statweb.stanford.edu/~adembo/stat-310b/lnotes.pdf check page number 35

Comment: @bunny Literally, check any statement or proof of Markov's inequality, you'll see you need that condition. And in the notes you link, indeed... Theorem 1.3.13, Markov's inequality, **$\psi$ is a function taking values in $[0,\infty]$**. I.e., **nonnegative.**

Comment: yes $\psi$ should be non negative but there is no such condition on the random variable $X$

Comment: Because the bound is with the expectation of $\psi(X)$. $\psi(X)$ is the nonnegative random variable there. @bunny (I am going to stop replying now, it's late.)

Comment: i just got that the bound should be $\mathbb P\{X_n\ge n\epsilon\}\le  \frac{\mathbb E(|X_n|)}{n\epsilon}=0$ but can you please tell me how did you get the estimate you had written

Comment: @bunny You do not have $\mathbb{E}[|X_n|] = 0$:  $\mathbb{E}[|X_n|]$ and  $\mathbb{E}[X_n]$ are not the same thing. Now, the bound I got comes from the definition of a normal definition (and of the [complementary error function erfc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Complementary_error_function)).

Answer (score 0):

For $Z_n \sim N(0,1)$ actually it's even easier to show that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(|Z_n|\geq n \varepsilon) = 2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(Z_n \geq n \varepsilon)
$$
if you consider MGF for $Z_n, \varphi_{Z_{n}}(s) = e^{\frac{s^2}{2}}, s>0$. Since $\varphi$ is positive, you can use Markov inequality directly and it's easy to show that
$$
P(Z_n> r) \leq e^{\frac{s^2}{2} - sr}
$$
By taking the derivative of the upper bound, you can show that it achieve its minumum at $s=r$, in this case $r= n \varepsilon$, so
$$
P(Z_n > n \varepsilon ) \leq e^{-\frac{(n \varepsilon)^2}{2}}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(|Z_n|\geq n \varepsilon) \leq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{(n \varepsilon)^2}{2}} < \infty
$$
because the corresponding integral converges (error function). As a result,
$$
P(\limsup |\frac{X_n}{n}|> \varepsilon) = P( |\frac{X_n}{n}|> \varepsilon \ i.o.) = 0
$$
and
$$
\frac{X_{n}}{n} \to_n 0 \ a.s.
$$